# Codeignighter Cart class base fee

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a unique shop where some products incur a base fee, lets say

A photographer charges $20 for the first hour then $1 there-after.

I am passing a variable into my codeignighter cart ; so for 5 hours I would pass the variable into cart->insert();

```
$item['id'] = 1;
$item['qty'] = 5;
$item['base'] = 20.00;
```

I made some changes to the cart class so this would work and has been fine so far, what I now need and cant seem to figure this out is when there are options it considers it a different product and this fee is charged once per rowid.

I would like my class to only allow 1 charge for the item regardless of the various options.

Below are the three functions I created inside my Cart class
and I call `set_base($item)` in the _save_cart() function.

```
private function set_base($item)
{

    if( $this->base_exist($item) )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Only allow the base cost for 1 row id, it doesnt matter which one, just one
    $this->_base_indexes['rowid'][$item['id']] = $item['rowid'];
    $this->_cart_contents['cart_total'] += $item['base'];

    return TRUE;

}

private function base_exist($item)
{
    if ( array_key_exists($item['id'] , $this->_base_indexes['applied']) ) 
    {

        if ( ( $item['rowid'] == $this->_base_indexes['applied'][$item['id']] ) )
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
private function base_reset()
{

    $this->_base_indexes = array();
    $this->_base_indexes['applied'] = array();

    return $this->_base_indexes;

}
```

Inside _save_cart();
I call

```
$this->base_reset();
```

Inside the cart_contents() loop I have added;

```
        if(isset($val['base'])) 
        {
            $this->set_base($val);
        }

        $this->_cart_contents['cart_total'] += ($val['price'] * $val['qty']);
```

Hope this was clear :/

Answer (score 0):

OK i changed it a little bit,
the foreach loop in the save_cart function now looks like; and I can remove the three functions I had before.

```
    foreach ($this->_cart_contents as $key => $val)
    {
        // We make sure the array contains the proper indexes
        if ( ! is_array($val) OR ! isset($val['price']) OR ! isset($val['qty']))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if(isset($val['base'])) 
        {
            //If it doesnt exist, add the fee
            if (!(isset($this->_base_indexes[$val['id']]) == $val['rowid']) ) 
            {
                $this->_base_indexes[$val['id']] = $val['rowid'];
                $this->_cart_contents['cart_total'] += $val['base'];
                $sub = ($this->_cart_contents[$key]['price'] * $this->_cart_contents[$key]['qty']) + $val['base'];
            }
            else
            {
                //$this->_cart_contents[$key]['base'] = 0;
                $sub = ($this->_cart_contents[$key]['price'] * $this->_cart_contents[$key]['qty']);
            }

        }


        $this->_cart_contents['cart_total'] += ($val['price'] * $val['qty']);
        $this->_cart_contents['total_items'] += $val['qty'];
        $this->_cart_contents[$key]['subtotal'] = $sub;
    }
```